# Function fields defined for irreducible curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm working with the definition of function field for projective curves found in *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach* (Garrity):

> Let the function field $\mathcal{K}(V)$ for the curve $V = V(P)$,
>   where $P=(x,y,z)$ is a homogeneous polynomial, be the set of all
>   rational functions $\frac{f(x,y,z)}{g(x,y,z)}$ where
>
> (1) both $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous of the same degree,
>
> (2) $P$ does not divide $g$, and
>
> (3) $\frac{f_{1}(x,y,z)}{g_{1}(x,y,z)}$ is identified with $\frac{f_{2}(x,y,z)}{g_{2}(x,y,z)}$ if $P$ divides $f_{1}g_{2}-f_{2}g_{1}$.

This definition doesn't specify that $V$ must be irreducible, which irks me. Say $P = (q(x,y,z))^{2}$ and let $r(x,y,z)$ be a homogeneous polynomial such that $\deg (r) = \deg (q)$ and $q \nmid r$. Then we'd have that $\left( \frac{q}{r} \right)^{2} = 0$ in $\mathcal{K}(V)$, making $\mathcal{K}(V)$ not a field.

Should we require $V$ to be irreducible for this definition or am I messing something up?

Comment: Yes. In your example the ring is non-reduced (has nilpotents) and in general the curve (or other scheme) could be reducible. The appropriate notion is the sheaf of total quotient rings; in the case of an affine reducible but non-reduced, say, curve, we localize at the non-zero-divisors.

Comment: I don't have any sheaf theory under my belt, but I have a vague idea of what you're talking about. As it stands, we'll have to restrict a curve to be irreducible with this definition, but you're saying that even if it is reducible, we can look at the resultant ring of fractions, localize at the set of non-zero divisors, and work with that instead?

Comment: Yes. What you get isn't a field, but it does include all the rational functions we can define on the beast.

Comment: The denominator $g$ isn't allowed to be a zero-divisor. So you need to replace (2) by $\forall h, gh \in (P) \implies h \in (P)$